# C++ compilation error, no match for operator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operators

I'm trying to build for android some C++ code, that already working on win32. I have a problem, with overloaded operators. For example:

Code:

```
Vector2 uv0 =  textures.back()->m_uv0;
Vector2 uvt =  textures.back()->m_uvt;

uv0 = m_uv0 + Vector2(uv0.x * m_uvt.x, uv0.y * m_uvt.y) + Vector2(0.01f,0.01f);
```

Where **Vector2** is a class declarated above. The declaration of it is:

```
class Vector2
{
public:
//Constructors
Vector2() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f){}
Vector2(GLfloat _x, GLfloat _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
Vector2(double _x, double _y) : x(static_cast<float>(_x)), y(static_cast<float>(_y)) {}
Vector2(int _x, double _y) : x(static_cast<float>(_x)), y(static_cast<float>(_y)) {}
Vector2(double _x, int _y) : x(static_cast<float>(_x)), y(static_cast<float>(_y)) {}
Vector2(int _x, int _y) : x(static_cast<float>(_x)), y(static_cast<float>(_y)) {}
Vector2(GLfloat * pArg) : x(pArg[0]), y(pArg[1]) {}
Vector2(const Vector2 & vector) : x(vector.x), y(vector.y) {}

//Vector's operations
GLfloat Length();
Vector2 & Normalize();
Vector2 operator + (Vector2 & vector);
Vector2 & operator += (Vector2 & vector);
Vector2 operator - ();
Vector2 operator - (Vector2 & vector);
Vector2 & operator -= (Vector2 & vector);
Vector2 operator * (GLfloat k);
Vector2 & operator *= (GLfloat k);
Vector2 operator / (GLfloat k);
Vector2 & operator /= (GLfloat k);
Vector2 & operator = (Vector2 vector);
Vector2 Modulate(Vector2 & vector);
GLfloat Dot(Vector2 & vector);
void Set(GLfloat _x, GLfloat _y);

//access to elements
GLfloat operator [] (unsigned int idx);

//data members
float x;
float y;
};
```

The definition of this class I won't list here, because it doesn't metter.

But unfortunately I recive an error:

```
G:/PROJECT266/projects/PROJECT266//jni/../jni/SBE/source/Sprite.cpp: In member function'void Sprite::AddTex(TEX::GUItex)':
G:/PROJECT266/projects/PROJECT266//jni/../jni/SBE/source/Sprite.cpp:103:57: error: no match for 'operator+' in '((Sprite*)this)->Sprite::m_uv0 + Vector2((uv0.Vector2::x *((Sprite*)this)->Sprite::m_uvt.Vector2::x), (uv0.Vector2::y * ((Sprite*)this)->Sprite::m_uvt.Vector2::y))'
G:/PROJECT266/projects/PROJECT266//jni/../jni/SBE/source/Sprite.cpp:103:57: note: candidates are:
G:/PROJECT266/projects/PROJECT266//jni/../jni/SBE/source/SBMath.h:38:10: note: Vector2 Vector2::operator+(Vector2&)
G:/PROJECT266/projects/PROJECT266//jni/../jni/SBE/source/SBMath.h:38:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Vector2' to 'Vector2&'
```

But, if I rewrite the code above like this:

```
Vector2 uv0 =  textures.back()->m_uv0;
Vector2 uvt =  textures.back()->m_uvt;

Vector2 vec1 = Vector2(uv0.x * m_uvt.x, uv0.y * m_uvt.y);
Vector2 vec2 = Vector2(0.01f,0.01f);

uv0 = m_uv0 + vec1 + vec2;
```

There wouldn't be any errors during compilation. 
I can't understand, what is the cause of this silly error.
I would be very pleased, if you explain me how to solve this problem.

Comment: What compiler were you using on win32?  It was wrong to accept that code.

Comment: @aschepler unfortunately MSVC strays from the standard... I wouldn't be surprised if it allowed this :/

Comment: Some pages suggest this was fixed in MSVC 2003.  I was just wondering what version.

Comment: I were using MSVC Express 2012. And this code even works without any problems.

Comment: I've understood my mistake. Thanks a lot to everybody.
If I didn't port my code to android, I wouldn't know about this issue. It is very strange, that MSVC strays from standart so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to bind an *r-value* to a *non-const reference*.

This line:

```
uv0 = m_uv0 + Vector2(uv0.x * m_uvt.x, uv0.y * m_uvt.y) + Vector2(0.01f,0.01f);
```

is equivalent to: (I replaced the parameters with `PARAMS` to make my example more readable):

```
uv0 = (m_uv0.operator+(Vector2(PARAMS))).operator+(Vector2(PARAMS));
```

Here `Vector2(PARAMS)` will create a temporary object. That is you are trying to pass an r-value reference to your operator overload and the compiler will not find a match as your operator is declared as:

```
Vector2 operator+ (Vector2& vector);
```

For more info about why temporaries can't be bound to non-const references see this: [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

**In the second example** you first declare two `Vector2` objects and then pass them to the operator as *l-value* references which matches your operator overload.

One way to solve the issue and let the operator overload take both l-value and r-value references is to declare it as taking a reference to `const` as it is perfectly fine to bind an r-value to a reference to `const`. See the answer by [krsteeve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18433975/873025) for how this can be done.

In general you should always declare functions taking references as taking reference to `const` if you don't intend to modify the argument.

**Examples of reference binding:**

```
Vector2& ref1 = Vector2(); // Error, trying to bind r-value to non-const ref.
Vector2 v;
Vector2& ref2 = v; // OK, v is an l-value reference.

// It is however OK to bind an r-value to a const reference:
const Vector& ref3 = Vector2(); // OK.
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass in temporary objects as non-const references. Change the signature of your `operator +` to take a const references:

```
Vector2 operator + (const Vector2 & vector);
```

The reason your second sample works is that you're now naming the Vector2 objects, they're no longer temporary.

Comment: The first operand should probably also allow `const`.